# Hedging long municipal bond portfolio using BMA/SIFMA

Tags: hedging, fixed-income

A question from one of my members.

Anyone have experience hedging a long municipal bond portfolio using BMA / SIFMA swaps? Anything you can share regarding sizing and structuring the swap and monitoring / adjusting it over time? How effective has this swap been in different market scenarios?

Comment: I've added a bounty in the hopes that someone can answer this.

Comment: Any update from your user? Does [Akshay's answer](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1795/hedging-long-municipal-bond-portfolio-using-bma-sifma/1817#1817) help?

Comment: Chris I passed the answer here to my member and there is no indication if it answers all of his question. http://www.quantnet.com/forum/threads/hedging-municipal-bonds.7294/

Comment: Thanks for the update. I wish he had stated what he thought of the solution. I'm not qualified to assess this topic, so I just awarded the bounty for Akshay's effort.

Comment: Can someone please explain me how to mitigate basis risk in a bond portfolio with swaps against parallel shift and non-parallel shift of yield curve.

Comment: @Elango You need to ask a new question. Don't post on someone else's question.

Answer (score 3):

(1) Assuming the portfolio comprises mostly senior VRDOs or comparable muni-floaters, one way of sizing a SIFMA-indexed swap would be to find the historical root-mean-square volatility of the  coupon fixings of the portfolio constituents and weight them by their percentage nominal to get a proxy for the portfolio volatility.

Do the same for the SIFMA index. The ratio of the two volatilities can then be used a scaling factor for sizing the swap. (NB: This is certainly not the best way to do it, but just a useful method to get a "feel" for the swap size).

(2) With fixed-rate munis, the regular key-rate durations-based swap-hedging method should be applicable (ie calculate the dollar-duration of your portfolio with respect to rates for key tenors and then swap that fixed-rate exposure for a floating one).

(3) With subordinated debt and a collateralized swap, the credit quality of your portfolio (assuming part of it is pledged as collateral) comes into play - you might end up paying a massive *fixed* basis over the par swap rate which will obliterate the advantage gained by hedging the volatility of the floating rate.

(4) As far as adjustment of the swap goes: at each reset period, see if you can get a "cheaper" basis above par-swap rate if the floating-rate volatility or credit quality of your portfolio change over the reset period.